# Conventions for settings file in open source software

Tags: php, git, open-source

I am developing a PHP application that needs access to a database and I am using git for version control. I want to create a settings file that will store the user name, password, and other application-specific settings. However, I don't want to risk committing it to my repository.

I currently manage this by creating settings.ignore.php file in the same directory and listing it in my .gitignore file.

**settings.php:**

```
<?php
$dbUser = '';
$dbPass = '';
$dbName = '';
include 'settings.ignore.php';
```

**settings.ignore.php:**

```
<?php
$dbUser = 'admin';
$dbPass = 'secret';
$dbName = 'database';
```

Is this the best or most common way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, configuration settings should be stored outside the application code.

This way, you can quite simply update the application, without touching the configuration. For example, have a look at the folder structure of a Symfony project:

```
app/       # configuration, log files, cache
bin/       # "binaries", i.e. helper scripts for the command line
src/       # YOUR application code, i.e. code you wrote specifically for your app
vendor/    # 3RD PARTY code, i.e. Symfony and other external code
web/       # public files: images, JS, CSS, font files
```

The configuration is environment specific and, depending which one it is, to be found in different files:

```
app/config/config_dev.yml     # config for your development environment
app/config/config_test.yml    # config for your unit tests
app/config/config_prod.yml    # config for production/target environments
app/config/config_longjon.yml # if you want, set up your own env. type
app/config/config.yml         # common config for all of them, inherited
```

Btw, as you see, Symfony doesn't use PHP files for configuration, but YAML (or XML). In this case, it is of course *very important* to store the configuration outside the document root.

I would recommend downloading a number of widely used frameworks written in different languages, maybe read their documentation, to see how they handle this category of questions.

They have usually put very much thought into these things, and many seasoned developers were usually involved.

Comment: Thanks, but this still has the problem that I need to include a sample XML file in my source.

Comment: You do indeed, but where's the problem? A YML or XML file is perfect for storing configurational parameters. It is however true that parsing such a file can be “expensive”, so it would make sense to cache the parameters in a serialized PHP file.